# Последовательная отправка нескольких Ajax запросов

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть функция `listAjaxOneOrder`, которая отправляет Ajax запрос, получает один заказ и вставляет его в `#result-list`:

```
function listAjaxOneOrder() { 
   $.ajax({
       $("#result-list").append(result.name).fadeIn('fast');
   })
}
```

С помощью функции `listAjax` хочу последовательно вывести сразу несколько заказов на одной странице, вызывая в `while` функцию `listAjaxOneOrder`:

```
function listAjax() {
    while (iOrderList <= m_data) {
        listAjaxOneOrder()
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том, что они все вызываются параллельно. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/jQuery.ajax/ в самом начале про опцию async. Это не то, что ты хочешь?

Comment: спасибо. После 8 запроса появляется сообщение антивируса "заблокирован переход по фишенговой ссыкли", с чем это может быть связанно?

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы эта функция распространялась только на этот запрос?

Comment: не знаю - это будет правильный ответ. никогда не надо было.

Comment: нее, это не подходит, все блокируется во время такой загрузки

Comment: это там явно написано. иначе асинхронно, то есть все вместе

Comment: @splash58 `async: false` в подавляющем большинстве случаев является плохим решением.

Answer (score 1):

Походу вот то, что ты ищешь.

```js
urls = ['http://echo.jsontest.com/id/1', 'http://echo.jsontest.com/id/2', 'http://echo.jsontest.com/id/3']
promise = $.when();
$.each(urls, function(index, url){
    promise = promise.then(function(){
        return $.ajax(url);
    }).then(function(result){
        $('#log').append(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```